# Microsoft Cognitive Speech SDK(js) not working well on safari

Tags: reactjs, azure, macos, safari, azure-cognitive-services

I am using microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk 1.31.0 with react.js frontend.
It works well on google chrome browser, but when it goes on safari it does not work well.
text-to-speech function (speakTextAsync) is not working at all and speech-to-text(recognizeOnceAsync) does work only after pressing button and not afterwards.
Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks, everyone!

I tried to reproduce the error on google chrome, but I could not.
I think it is related to safari's feature to allow audio input/output only with user interaction (eg pressing buttons ...)

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Speech React sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureSpeechReactSample) has just been updated to use JS Speech SDK v1.32.0. Running that sample on Safari 16.6, recognizeOnceAsync works each time (once mic permission is granted).

For text-to-speech, an additional input component integrating SpeechSynthesizer will be added to the sample soon.

EDIT: The sample has been updated to include SpeechSynthesizer.speakTextAsync usage.

Comment: Thanks. Will the tts feature work on new version?

Comment: If it doesn't, and can be fixed on the Speech SDK side, it will be fixed. I'll update the original answer once it's done and working.

Comment: ok. I will wait.

Comment: The sample is updated and has been tested on Safari. Could you take a look and see if it works for you?